# Laravel Passport, get user from token give null

Tags: laravel, authentication, passport.js, access-token

I am working a laravel API by using laravel passport to authenticate
index function

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $userId=auth('api')->user()->id;
        dd(auth('api')->user()->id);
        return User::find($userId)->conversations()->with('messages','otherUser')->get();
    }
```

test_index function

```
public function test_index(): void
    {
        $response = $this->withHeaders([
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiIxIiwianRpIjoiNDJiNWQyZGZlYzMzYWY5ZjczY2JlZjQ4NDAzMGVkZGZhNjE4ZWNkZDFmOGZjYzM3NTVmMGE2Y2QxZGNkZGEwYmY1MTFhZDBhMTA5NDI2YTAiLCJpYXQiOjE2OTA1ODgxNzYuMzk2MzEzLCJuYmYiOjE2OTA1ODgxNzYuMzk2MzE1LCJleHAiOjE3MjIyMTA1NzYuMjg3ODcxLCJzdWIiOiIyNiIsInNjb3BlcyI6W119.P9890yV3ra5fjlfq3D7qzbv9VxFlJZoXDZxP1Z-DX13P60ND9OwaFSemd7oBq_mydeRgnoNIN9m8RQ7neLdCW1TdNwnufwqcaYuSp4Bb0UucVN-cbv77xc58levfnIddUK54M08CnoWYKmH3n4vzlv0npdUOzmirKsAWp8qMe3zD9_5HiN0NEDWPwQHTu9KitKglradkE6naOMfkYv_uzBvWbfLnCTqW-zHtOzycxD-U5N9TQCq2zRPwMj2ffF-GIeSB6hArHQxmdAReGA4KKdWkvnyOMzLDRnXthuJbZhw38Cjr1at9j5Tg87FDAXfqOUflhZZfM759zVaPyvSH7hUT0g33JMTNpdGCE04h4i2Z26k8CPEcS_JQKSSkk7VJofh4-bgXW5i0PzP82Rnpw89B_3sZbqXjzoItivSL8as7S5hzAO9hT653PqzrUbFdcMnXTbZDRVbp6Qgp7s6qJPCk9yhJK8K2Wz-Ecgiu81dz4Mw7rLzhXlQrlTtOISoY0kMuYElDE-cj2T7nTy69ZVIURpucg3eEfuiIuZ3Qv-jedjU6iElNACQu9FnUmAcc_PqLMSJw_ZPwKf9e_RVzm7Kckc7kJ1l5NalzezaWbzx1CXJlmVJ7RLtGkXsSEFsaaKVUV7bBWr7KLYRJ-ADO4ppy2KBNaOmsnnC3ozKuiCk',
        ])->get('/api/conversations');

        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
```

Now when I run test with `dd()` index it return 1 that is correct value, but when I remove it I am getting error:

> Attempt to read property "id" on null

What's wrong with this code?